# Robot Framework - How to use Run Keyword with a named argument

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework to test the functionality of a webpage and, long story short, I'm creating a keyword to wrap executing a webpage check with [Run Keyword and Return Status](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/5.0/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) and giving it the keyword via arguments (which are accepted in the same way as Run Keyword). Importantly, the wrapper will disable the execution of [Register Keyword to Run on Failure](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Register%20Keyword%20To%20Run%20On%20Failure), a SeleniumLibrary keyword which will initiate a call to capture a screenshot by default. It is useful for debugging but creates some file bloat whenever Run Keyword and Return Status returns false.

I have the keyword mostly figured out, as demonstrated here:

```
Library    BuiltIn
Library    SeleniumLibrary

Get Status From Keyword
    [Documentation]    This will prevent Run Keyword And Return Status from triggering a screenshot if it returns false
    ...                This should help to reduce file bloat in test case results
    [Arguments]    ${kw}    @{args}

    ${failureKeyword}=    Register Keyword To Run On Failure    NONE

    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    ${kw}    @{args}
    Register Keyword To Run On Failure    ${failureKeyword}

    [Return]    ${status}
```

There is a problem where I am unable to use named arguments (i.e. timeout=20), and I think I understand why. The problem stems from the @{args} argument. [According to the Robot Framework documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/5.0/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#named-arguments-with-variables), it is not possible to use named arguments as part of a list because it can't interpret the '=' literally if it's part of a string (as is the values of @{args}).

Normally, the solution would be to implement this as a Python method using **kwargs to allow [freely named arguments](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/5.0/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#free-keyword-arguments-kwargs), which I have attempted to implement as such but I am running into problems of the libraries themselves being... stubborn...

```
# These imports are almost definitely not right this is just my best guesswork at their location
from SeleniumLibrary.keywords.runonfailure import runonfailure
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def Get_Status_From_Keyword(name, **args):
    '''This will prevent Run Keyword And Return Status from triggering a screenshot if it returns false
    This should help to reduce file bloat in test case results'''

    failureKeyword = selenium.register_keyword_to_run_on_failure(NONE)

    status = BuiltIn.run_keyword_and_return_status(name, args)
    selenium.register_keyword_to_run_on_failure(failureKeyword)

    return status
```

Thus far, the implementation I've tried will fail to import the file, and I frankly don't know if my implementation will work like how I expect. I'm planning on settling on a workaround for the time being but, for the sake of inquiry, **what would be the most appropriate way to call Run Keyword using named arguments?** Either in a .robot file or in Python will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this example. Isn't it what you are trying to achieve?

**test.robot**

```
*** Variables ***
${keyword_in_variables}  Log To Console
&{kwargs_in_variables}  message=Message from variables definition  no_newline=False

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    # kw stores the name of the keyword
    ${kw}=  Set Variable  Log To Console

    # kwargs stores dictionary of keyword arguments
    &{kwargs}=  Create Dictionary  message=Message from test dict  no_newline=False

    # run keyword using kwargs with & operator. It will unpack dictionary as python kwargs
    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status  ${kw}  &{kwargs}

Test 2
    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status  ${keyword_in_variables}  &{kwargs_in_variables}
```

**Output**

```
==============================================================================
Test1                                                                         
==============================================================================
Test 1                                                                ..Message from test dict
Test 1                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 2                                                                Message from variables definition
Test 2                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test1                                                                 | PASS |
2 tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

You are looking for `&` operator which is something like python kwargs unpacking.

Read more about it in robotframework here:
[Dictionary variable syntax](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#toc-entry-307)

Answer (score 0):

The post by pL3b didn't quite answer my question, but it did remind me that named arguments are similar to dictionary entries. This prompted me to revisit the Robot Framework documentation on free named arguments to understand how dictionaries play into the provided examples. I realized that the examples use a list followed by a dictionary in its arguments. This made me realize that I can act similarly in my implementation.

I believe that the following implementation will allow a user to pass any keyword and arguments, including named ones, and then effectively "mute" the SeleniumLibrary's Run On Failure keyword while getting the result of Run Keyword and Return Status:

```
Get Status From Keyword
    [Documentation]    Prevent Run Keyword And Return Status from triggering a screenshot if it returns false.
    ...                This should help to reduce file bloat in test case results
    ...                Ensure named arguments are written last in the given arguments
    [Arguments]    ${kw}    @{args}    &{kwargs}

    ${failureKeyword}=    Register Keyword To Run On Failure    NONE

    ${status}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    ${kw}    @{args}    &{kwargs}
    Register Keyword To Run On Failure    ${failureKeyword}

    [Return]    ${status}
```